# Hairlines when creating a PDF, Acrobat(?)

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, adobe-acrobat, rendering

I have been googling this for a few days, tinkering with Acrobat settings, trying to locate "Save as PDF" settings and whatnot; no result so far...

Seems I can't find a related setting...
What should I look for: Print quality? DPI / PPI or similar?
Is it hidden somewhere deep down in the GUI-dungeons of Windows 10?

**The problem:**
These two images show the differing result of Word document to PDF conversion done by me (thin hairlines) and others (two persons).

*edit: The (Zoomed in) black lines (below) are hairlines (set to 0.5pt [ 1/144" ] or some such) in the Word doc.*

*edit: The PDFs display consistently on different machines including those they were created on; i.e. any differing settings in **DISPLAY** settings should not be at play here.*

Any advice or tips regarding how to make the result be the SAME (regardless of person / computer /login) is welcome

*edit1:* Images: ZOOMED in, the black hairlines became "thick"
**(set to be 0.5 pt in the original / source -Word doc)**
[image: Coarse lines]
[image]

---

*edit2:*
Same settings in both Acrobat Reader DC AND Acrobat DC (Pro) [ both installed installed, reader/enforced, Pro/requested], renders thin lines:
[image: Settings-for-Reader-AND-Pro-where-lines-are-thin].com/I0C05.png

Settings in computer that renders THICK lines verified to be the same as above; conclusion the line thickness is not dependent on "display" settings.

Comment: What thin hairlines where?

Comment: @DavidPostill the user is reffering to the thickness of the border of the boxes.

Comment: Those (Zoomed in) black lines are hairlines (set to 0.5pt [ 1/144" ] or some such) in the Word doc.

Comment: Table border setting verified to be 0.5pt (1/2 pt)

Comment: Sometimes PDF software will render visual elements (as they appear on your screen) inaccurately as opposed to what would actually be printed out.  Funnily enough, these usually involve table borders, line thicknesses, line patterns, etc.  I'd learned to live with them, but I can't imagine how infuriating that'd be to deal with if you worked in the digital graphics sector.  In your case, are you purely trying to ensure the proper thickness is rendered graphically onto your or someone else's display?  Or what's your use case/criteria?  These details might you get more relevant answers.

Comment: The framing is part of the visual appearance of a specific report, to be forwarded between international companies. So the PFDs appearance is part of the impression made by the producer of the report, "professionalism" and all that. A good looking report or not.

Comment: https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/printer-marks-hairlines-acrobat-pro.html - how to "Fix" ONE, OPENED PDF, but not the PDF-creation in general ; which is what I look for here.

Comment: helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/… - how to "Fix" ONE, OPENED PDF, but not the PDF-creation in general ; which is what I look for here. <= Does not work (NOT applicable?) here, are these "lines" at all?!?

Comment: Please post online an example Word & PDF files that we can examine, to see what are these hairlines.

Comment: Are you sure both pdfs were created in the same way? If you have Acrobat PRO, in Word you will see a menu option "save as Acrobat PDF". However, you can also go on "save as", and choose "pdf" as Filetype (rather than docx): then Word will use the inbuilt pdf creator. Differences in output can be considerable.

Comment: I'll try to post examples of all possible creation methods, from both computers. So far the two (so far identified) differing computers has been consistently creating incorrect hairlines. This is work done in between normal work tasks, so slightly slow in progress.

Comment: In Word, are the hairlines inserted as shape? or as borders of a table?

Comment: Borders of a table (been buzy at work, still intend to upload examples)

Answer (score 0):

The difference might relate to a difference in the settings of Acrobat
on both computers, and not to the Word document itself.

You might try creating the PDF on your computer while turning on and off
"Enhance thin lines" in the Page Display area of the Preferences.

This (or some other setting) might be behind the difference in line thickness.

Comment: I find "Enhance thin lines" to be unlikely to be the problem, but will try it out... (not on location right now)

Comment: Display settings verified to be the same on (at least one) of the "offending" computers.